# Complexity of an optimisation problem in 3D

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, search-problem

I have a collection $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ of $N$ particles and there is a function $f : P^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. I want to find which configuration of the system minimizes the value of $f$.

Can this problem (or similar ones) be reduced to TSP? Could you point me to literature on the topic?

In my application, $f$ is the [atomic van der waals force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force), which for each pair of particles of atoms is attractive or repulsive depending on some predefined thresholds.

In addition, it would be great to have a list of concrete examples of problems that can be reduced to TSP.

Comment: What is your function, you should add more information.

Comment: I removed the overly broad question about problems reducible to TSP; the main question seems to be about a specific class of problems. However, as it is the question is too vague, as Patrick notes in his answer: votes to close as not constructive. Please add more information, in particular about $f$.

Comment: the function is the atomic van der waals energy, which for each pair of particles of atoms is attractive or repulsive depending on some predefined thresholds

Comment: What is a "configuration", and how does $f$ compute a value for it; sum of pairwise energies, maximum pairwise energy, ...? Regarding a list of problems, see Patricks's answer or [Garey/Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability); I doubt such a list will be useful for you, though.

Comment: A configuration is the specification of 3D coordinates for all particles. The value of the function is the some of pairwise VDW energies.

Answer (score 8):

Since TSP is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), most problems you'll encounter in practice can be.  (NP is a pretty general class.)  A [classic paper of Karp](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf) gives a large number of other NP-complete problems that, by definition, can be reduced to TSP.

Comment: TSP is NP-Hard, it's optimization problem not decision.

Comment: "Is there a tour of cost at most $k$?" is a decision problem.

Comment: This is decision version of TSP, and normally when someone says TSP, means optimization  version, like many other NP-Hard problems. Also note that I downvoted you not because of just this, you answered the question without knowing exact problem, may be it's in $P$, IMO your answer doesn't deserves to get any upvote.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, the search and decision versions of travelling salesman are polynomial-time reducible to one another, so in the context of this question, the distinction doesn't matter. Problems in P are also in NP of course, so I don't understand the last point you are trying to make.

Comment: @Aaron, First of all IMO should say decision version of TSP is NP-Compelete, anyway may be you're not agree with this, but I'm saying this answer shouldn't get upvote, would you tell me what was the problem which answered here? to get upvotes? actually when you don't know OP's function (which is related to coordinations) how someone can say it's NP-x problem? we can't guess something in the air and then say this is an answer to your question.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, the question is "Which search/optimization problems can be reduced to the famous "Travel Salesman Problem"?". The answer is exactly the set of problems in NP.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I don't quite follow your reasoning. Certainly anything in NP can be reduced to either the decision or optimization variant of TSP. So, in that sense, this answer is accurate. What the answer doesn't do is to say which class the OP's problem is in... but that doesn't make the answer wrong, possibly just incomplete. More importantly, it provides a very clear test for whether his problem can be reduced to either TSP: is it in NP? That's a question we can't answer without the objective function; see my answer.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I think Louis gave a great answer... +1)

Comment: @Patrick87, First of all we can reduce all NPC problems to decision version of TSP, but it's not good to say TSP is NPC, that's my opinion, but you can read my second comment to understand reason of my downvote to this question, I don't like read answers to this question until it's not modified (to be clear), but if you think question is clear, OK, answer it. Also we have different definition for "great", you are free for your choice to upvote, also I have my own opinion and I can downvote by my rules. I don't like to argue about this simple thing (IMO).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Naturally, you're entitled to your opinion and your vote. Did you see that I already have an answer? I feel like, if anything, it reinforces the point you're making: the question is incomplete.

Comment: @Patrick87 Yes I think question is incomplete and I flag it so, and I left the comment for OP. So any answer to this question is general answer, and at least is not interesting for me, like the question. (if they are correct answers by given information, Also I saw your answer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3176/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-patrick87)

Answer (score 6):

A decision variant of the problem might be:

> Does there exist a configuration of the system such that the objective function assumes a value less than or equal to $y_0$?

It depends entirely upon the form of the objective function. Suppose that the objective function is constant, i.e., $f(x) = c$. Then a constant-time algorithm which solves the decision problem is to return $yes$ iff $c \le y_0$.

Suppose instead that $f(x)$ returns 0 if the Turing machine encoded by $x$ (according to some encoding scheme) halts on itself as input, and 1 otherwise. Then the decision problem is undecidable, since it would allow you to solve the Halting problem; in particular, it is not reducible to TSP.

(*Note: in order for the above to create a Halting-Problem scenario, there would need to be some restrictions on the allowed configurations, so that - for instance - only one configuration were possible. This could easily be encoded by the $f$; make all but exactly one configuration result in $f(x) = +\infty$*)

Comment: +1 This is definitely something I didn't cover, and between the two the question seems answered.